# Why is the output different from what I expected for a degree to radian conversion?

Tags: c++

I'll start off with the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Set Default Precision
int precision = 10;

int pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716;
int angle, degOrRad;
int angleP;

//Menu
int menu()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "--- Trigonometry Calculator ---" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the value of your desired angle => ";
    cin >> angle;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Is the angle in degree or in radian?" << endl;
    cout << "Input D if it is in degree," << endl;
    cout << "Input R if it is in radian. => ";
    cin >> degOrRad;
    return angle, degOrRad;
}

int main()
{
    menu();

    if (degOrRad == 'D')
        angleP = angle;
        angle = (angle*180)/pi;
        cout <<  angleP << " degrees = " << angle << " Radian";
}
```

I am trying to get the user to input the angle and tell me if it is a degree or a radian, and if it is a degree the program will have it converted into radian.

However when I ran the program, inputting 20 as the angle and then choosing degree outputs "0 degrees = 1200 radian".

Any idea where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `return angle, degOrRad;` doesn't do what you want. [Documentation for comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) Consider returning a `std::pair`, your own structure that aggregates `angle` and  `degOrRad`, or having two functions. I prefer the latter since a function should do one job.

Comment: `int pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716;` is equivalent to `int pi = 3;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your formula is wrong:

To convert degrees to radians, its: `radians = degrees * pi / 180`.

#### Your variables have the wrong type:

Any variables that have a decimal component (`pi`, `angleP`, probably `angle` as well), should be doubles or floats, not ints.

#### Misleading indentation

C does not use leading whitespace (like python) for code blocks. Multi statement blocks should be wrapped in `{}`.

```
if (degOrRad == 'D') {
    angleP = angle;
    angle = (angle*180)/pi;
    cout <<  angleP << " degrees = " << angle << " Radian";
}
```

*Thanks user4581301 for catching this one!*

Comment: Shoot I didn't notice that my formula was wrong. Thanks for that. Now I am getting the correct radian values. However the final output still says 0 degrees (which angleP is supposed to hold), any idea why?

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you. That fixed it. But why does declaring degOrRad as a char fix this? When its an int it already triggers the if loop when I input D, why does the second line work but not the first? Sorry if I sound dumb as I am still new to the language.